# The text inside the DIV is too close to the DIV border

Tags: html, css

Hello everyone and good evening,

The text inside the DIV is too close to the DIV border.  How can I create space so the text is a little bit further from the border?

Thank you so much

Below you can find my css and you can also find [an example on my website](http://www.clihelp.org/script.php?cliCommandId=00106&code=WI) so you know what I am talking about. Thank you again.

```
 .text {
    background-color: #F1F1F1;
    width: 600px;
    margin: auto;
    border: 1px solid #73AD21;
    padding-top: -50px;
    padding-right: -60px;
    padding-bottom: -50px;
    padding-left: -20px;
}

pre {
    white-space: pre-wrap;       /* Since CSS 2.1 */
    white-space: -moz-pre-wrap;  /* Mozilla, since 1999 */
    white-space: -pre-wrap;      /* Opera 4-6 */
    white-space: -o-pre-wrap;    /* Opera 7 */
    word-wrap: break-word;       /* Internet Explorer 5.5+ */
}
```

Comment: Please provide a viable example via a code sharing utility such as Codepen.io, Jsfiddle.net, jsbin.com or use StackOverflows built-in editor to provide an example. Linking to your personal site is discouraged as you are potentially using this post to gain Ad revenue (not saying that is the case, just has been known to happen).

Comment: well you have to know padding can't not be negative value and set some padding for your text make it bit far from div

Comment: why your text use the nagative padding?

Comment: Note that negative padding values are invalid. https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/box.html#padding-properties

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just give `padding: 15px;`.

```
.text {
    background-color: #F1F1F1;
    width: 600px;
    margin: auto;
    border: 1px solid #73AD21;
    padding: 15px;
    }
```

You can increase the padding as you wish (i.e. `padding: 20px`).

Comment: Thanks.  Padding: 3px;  It was good enough for me.  Otherwise if I put 15px, yes the text looks good but the div extend all way to the far right.

Answer (score 0):

Add a little padding inside the div, that should do it for you.

```
.div {
  padding: 10px;
}
```